# Is the boundary of a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ a null measure set?

Tags: measure-theory

I'm not talking about Lebesgue measure but Jordan measure. Thank you!

Comment: Just a note: Lebesgue and Jordan measures coincide on Jordan-measurable sets

Comment: Isn't a closed disk compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and its boundary a circle, which has non zero measure?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 no, that has zero measure.

Comment: @OpenBall ah! I mixed up arc length and measure like a noob.......sorry

Comment: @OpenBall Sorry, I'm afraid I can't find the connexion between your note and my question. May you be more specific, please?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure#Extension_to_more_complicated_sets) on Jordan measure:

Equivalently, for a bounded set B the inner Jordan measure of B is the Lebesgue measure of the interior of B and the outer Jordan measure is the Lebesgue measure of the closure.[4] From this it follows that a bounded set is Jordan measurable if and only if its boundary has Lebesgue measure zero. (Or equivalently, if the boundary has Jordan measure zero; the equivalence holds due to compactness of the boundary.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. Note that a bounded set is Jordan measurable if and only if its boundary has Lebesgue measure zero

Now, take a fat Cantor set $C$, which has empty interior and the total length of the removed intervals is $1/2$ so $\lambda (C)>0$. Then, we have $(C\setminus C^0)=C$ and $(C\setminus C^0)^0=C^0=\emptyset $. i.e. $C$ is its own boundary. Thus,

$\lambda (\partial (\partial C))=\lambda ((C\setminus C^0)\setminus (C\setminus C^0)^0)=\lambda (C)>0.$

Comment: a fat cantor set is not Jordan measurable

Comment: right. and since it is its own boundary, the boundary is not Jordan measureable. So we have a compact set whose boundary is not Jordan mesasureable. Isn't that the question? Or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: you are correct, as long as we do not require the boundary to be measurable.

Comment: @chilangoincomprendido What is this $C^0$ notation? Does this mean interior?